# SPARQL and placeholders

Tags: sparql

In SQL (at least MySQL) there are `?` placeholders which allow to prepare a query once and then execute the query multiple times with different values.

Another use of placeholders is automatic quote of string variables (e.g. by an SQL engine).

What about similar "placeholders" in SPARQL?

I ask for any "standard" or nonstandard way to do this. If there are several incompatible implementations, please list all.

I consider to remember my C coding skills and implement this feature in Redland librdf. (Or is it already implemented in librdf? If yes, please explain how to use this feature.)

This is very important for my revolutionary open source software which I am going to create with librdf. I need this feature!

Comment: I think C is quite on the side here, so much that I doubt the usefulness of the tag.

Comment: There is no such standard for SPARQL and I I don't see why there should be. It has nothing to do with the language itself and is just some technical thing. Some APIs like Apache Jena support SPARQL query templates, but that's tool specific.

Comment: The "placeholders" you're talking about are generally known as "bound parameters," and they're used in "parameterized queries." They're not part of SQL, but they are part of ODBC (C), JDBC (Java), and various other SQL-focused programming APIs. You might look to Virtuoso's support for SPARQL-in-SQL, which lets you use SPARQL within ODBC, JDBC, and other data connections, but without much more detail about your revolutionary idea, it's impossible to say whether this will be of use to you.

Comment: @TallTed My idea: https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Automatic_transformation_of_XML_namespaces - I use SPARQL with RDF data, not with a database